# Self-inverse element in a field of prime characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Can you find an element $x$ in a field of characteristic $p$, ($p$ prime number), such that it is not equal to its inverse? And how this depends on the cardinality of the field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p=2$, there is one and only on such element, which is $1$.

Otherwise, there are two such elements, which are $1$ and $-1$.

This is so because $x=x^{-1}\iff x^2=1$.